# JFrame not showing despite no errors in code

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm new to using Java GUI's and I've copied word for word the HelloWorldSwing.java from java tutorials on oracle.com. Eclipse doesn't show any errors in my code and when I run it no window shows up and the program terminates after a second or two.

The code I used:

```
public class HelloWorldSwing {
/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was about to point out that the IDE is irrelevant & remove the tag, but since you posted what was (almost, just lacking an import) a [mre], I decided to try running it first (in an IDE that is *not* Eclipse). This is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P342N.png) (i.e. it works as expected). I don't offer support for IDEs, but it seems your Eclipse installation is broken or misconfigured.

Comment: OK .. just had a thought. Add `System.out.println("HelloWorldSwing");` in first line of the `main` and check it prints out. I put a lot of simple codes in the same 'test' package and only one of those examples is the 'default' one to run. Your Eclipse might be running a non-GUI'd app, that produces no (console visible) output.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried it and it printed fine, I'm probably gonna reinstall Eclipse once I get the chance. Thank you for the help though.